# Why function pointer isn't seen as point to function?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

Can't get to function through function pointer.

I'm writing a program that acts based on input(Body Mass Index calculator) for US and EU standards.
My point is to calculate BMIndex using one function"calcMethod", but trying to assign a pointer of other function to this one, leads to an error "called object isn't a function or function pointer". Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

float calcEU(float inputMass, float inputHeight)
{
    float BMIndexF;
    BMIndexF = inputMass / (inputHeight * inputHeight);
    return BMIndexF;
}

float calcUS(float inputMass, float inputHeight)
{
    float BMIndexF;
    BMIndexF = 703 * inputMass / (inputHeight * inputHeight);
    return BMIndexF;
}

int main()
{
    float BMIndex , inputMass , inputHeight;
    float heightColumn, massRow;
    float *calcMethod ;
    int Mod = 0;
    int countRow , countColumn;
    char unitStandard[2] , metricUnitH[2] , metricUnitM[2];

    printf("Your measure units? EU (kg, m) or US (lb, in) \n");
    gets(unitStandard);

    if(strcmp(unitStandard, "EU") == 0)
    {
        Mod = 1;
        strcpy(metricUnitH, "me");
        strcpy(metricUnitM, "kg");
        float (*calcMethod)(float , float) = &calcEU;
    }
        else if (strcmp(unitStandard, "US") == 0)
        {
            Mod = -1;
            strcpy(metricUnitH, "in");
            strcpy(metricUnitM, "lb");
            float (*calcMethod)(float , float) = &calcUS;
        }
            else
            {
                printf("Wrong Input");
                exit(-1);
            }

    printf("Introduce your body mass:\n");
    scanf("%f", &inputMass);

    printf("Introduce your height:\n");
    scanf("%f", &inputHeight);

    printf("\n");

    for(countRow = 0; countRow <= 5; countRow++)
    {
        for(countColumn = 0; countColumn <= 5; countColumn++)
        {
            heightColumn = inputHeight - 0.1 * (3 - countRow);
            massRow = inputMass - 1 * (3 - countColumn);

            if(countRow == 0 && countColumn == 0)  printf("H / M|");
            if(countRow == 0 && countColumn != 0)  printf("%.0f%s |", massRow , metricUnitM);
            if(countColumn == 0 && countRow != 0)  printf("%.1f%s |", heightColumn , metricUnitH);

            if(countRow != 0 && countColumn !=0)
            {
                //this line causes error
                BMIndex = (*calcMethod)(massRow , heightColumn);
                printf("%.2f |", BMIndex);
            }



        }

        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The commented line causes error: called object is not a function or function pointer

Expect it doesn't throw an error and work as intended.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message. Also indicate which line causes the error.

Comment: Finally, make your code example so that we can compile it and get the same error. In particular, add `main()` and all necessary variable declarations.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code. In particular, check the value of `Mod` to be sure it is in fact either -1 or 1.

Comment: `float (*calcMethod)(float , float) = &calcEU;
    }` the variable stops existing after `}`.

Comment: You are declaring and initializing two different `calcMethod` variables inside two different `if` blocks. Neither declaration is in scope when you call it in the code you showed. If you declare a single `calcMethod` variable (above the first `if` statement) and assign to the designed value within each `if` statement, then it should work.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've posted the entire code.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk I just tried in other file that you said, and in really doesn't get recognized outside if statement block.

Comment: @Ian Abbott Could you help this defining the pointer for "calcMethod" function?

Comment: Unrelated to your main problem, but: if you want a 2-letter response from the user, do *not* declare an array of size 2 to hold it, and even more importantly, never ever use `gets()` to read it! (1) The size needed to hold a string of length 2 is 3. (2) Using an array just barely big enough to hold the expected string is error-prone and pointless, since it doesn't prevent the user from trying to type something longer.  (3) The `gets` function is pathologically dangerous and has been removed from the C language standard and should never be used.

Comment: `float *calcMethod ;` this isn't a function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you declare `float *calcMethod;` -- a pointer to a float, not a pointer to a function.  You then redeclare it as a function pointer in your inner blocks, but that is just in those blocks -- where you try to call it you're trying to call the float pointer.

The fix is to declare it as a function pointer in the first place:

```
float (*calcMethod)(float, float);
```

then when you decide which to use, don't redeclare it, just assign it:

```
calcMethod = calcUS;
```

or

```
calcMethod = calcEU;
```

You also don't need the `*` to call through the pointer -- you can use just

```
BMIndex = calcMethod(massRow , heightColumn);
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have three `calcMethod`variables in the `main()` function. Thsi first one is a pointer to a float variable (which is obviously not a function pointer). The other two are function pointers, but they only exists inside their block of code.

If you define `calcMethod` only once as a function pointer, regardeless of other bugs in your code, that will work.

Here are the three changes :

```
int main()
{
    float BMIndex , inputMass , inputHeight;
    float heightColumn, massRow;
    float (*calcMethod)(float , float); // ****** CHANGE #1 HERE
    int Mod = 0;
    int countRow , countColumn;
    char unitStandard[2] , metricUnitH[2] , metricUnitM[2];

    printf("Your measure units? EU (kg, m) or US (lb, in) \n");
    gets(unitStandard);

    if(strcmp(unitStandard, "EU") == 0)
    {
        Mod = 1;
        strcpy(metricUnitH, "me");
        strcpy(metricUnitM, "kg");
        calcMethod = &calcEU; // ****** CHANGE #2 HERE
    }
        else if (strcmp(unitStandard, "US") == 0)
        {
            Mod = -1;
            strcpy(metricUnitH, "in");
            strcpy(metricUnitM, "lb");
            calcMethod = calcUS; // ****** CHANGE #3 HERE
        }
            else
            {
                printf("Wrong Input");
                exit(-1);
            }

    printf("Introduce your body mass:\n");
    scanf("%f", &inputMass);

    printf("Introduce your height:\n");
    scanf("%f", &inputHeight);

    printf("\n");

    for(countRow = 0; countRow <= 5; countRow++)
    {
        for(countColumn = 0; countColumn <= 5; countColumn++)
        {
            heightColumn = inputHeight - 0.1 * (3 - countRow);
            massRow = inputMass - 1 * (3 - countColumn);

            if(countRow == 0 && countColumn == 0)  printf("H / M|");
            if(countRow == 0 && countColumn != 0)  printf("%.0f%s |", massRow , metricUnitM);
            if(countColumn == 0 && countRow != 0)  printf("%.1f%s |", heightColumn , metricUnitH);

            if(countRow != 0 && countColumn !=0)
            {
                BMIndex = (*calcMethod)(massRow , heightColumn);
                printf("%.2f |", BMIndex);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you declaring different `calcMethod` variables in nested blocks and changing the wrong one. Also, the outer `calcMethod` variable you are trying to call isn't even a function pointer:

```
float *calcMethod ;

//assigning the pointer to function
//this subprogram is nested in main
if(Mod == 1) //Mod is just a variable
    {
        strcpy(metricUnitH, "me");
        strcpy(metricUnitM, "kg");

        // N.B. This is a different calcMethod variable!
        float (*calcMethod)(float , float) = &calcEU;
    } // N.B. calcMethod variable in previous block no longer exists!

if(Mod == -1)
    {
        strcpy(metricUnitH, "in");
        strcpy(metricUnitM, "lb");

        // N.B. This is a different calcMethod variable!
        float (*calcMethod)(float , float) = &calcUS;
    } // N.B. calcMethod variable in previous block no longer exists!

//the calcMethod is called
//this is nested in 2 for(s) and an if

// N.B. the calcMethod variable in this block is uninitialized, and
// it is not even a function pointer (it is a pointer to float) so
// this will not even compile....
BMIndex = (*calcMethod)(massRow , heightColumn);
```

The solution is to declare the outer `calcMethod` variable as a function pointer, and change the inner blocks to assign to the outer block's `calcMethod` variable instead of declaring a new one:

```
float (*calcMethod)(float, float) = calcUS;  // default to "US"

//assigning the pointer to function
//this subprogram is nested in main
if(Mod == 1) //Mod is just a variable
    {
        strcpy(metricUnitH, "me");
        strcpy(metricUnitM, "kg");
        calcMethod = calcEU;
    }
if(Mod == -1)
    {
        strcpy(metricUnitH, "in");
        strcpy(metricUnitM, "lb");
        calcMethod = calcUS;
    }

//the calcMethod is called
//this is nested in 2 for(s) and an if
BMIndex = (*calcMethod)(massRow , heightColumn);
```

I initialized the `calcMethod` to `calcUS` in case it has not been set by one of the `if` statements.  Alternatively, you could it initialize it to `NULL` and check for this as an error condition before you call `calcMethod`:

```
float (*calcMethod)(float, float) = NULL; // default to not set

// ...

if (calcMethod == NULL)
    {
        /* ERROR: calcMethod hasn't been set. */
        /* DO SOMETHING! */
    }
else
    {
        BMIndex = (*calcMethod)(massRow , heightColumn);
    }
```